# Print Contents Of A DataTable

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

Currently I have code which looks up a database table through a SQL connection and inserts the top five rows into a Datatable (Table).

```
using(SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStatement, _con))
{
    DataTable Table = new DataTable("TestTable");

    SqlDataAdapter _dap = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd);

    _con.Open();
    _dap.Fill(Table);
    _con.Close();
}
```

How do I then print the contents of this table to the console for the user to see?

After digging around, is it possible that I should bind the contents to a list view, or is there a way to print them directly? I'm not concerned with design at this stage, just the data.

Comment: are .Open() and .Close() not needed if you've wrapped everything in using?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

you can try this code :

```
foreach(DataRow dataRow in Table.Rows)
{
    foreach(var item in dataRow.ItemArray)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

**Update 1**

```
DataTable Table = new DataTable("TestTable");
using(SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStatement, _con))
{
    SqlDataAdapter _dap = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd);
    _con.Open();
    _dap.Fill(Table);
    _con.Close();

}
Console.WriteLine(Table.Rows.Count);
foreach(DataRow dataRow in Table.Rows)
{
    foreach(var item in dataRow.ItemArray)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26640/discussion-between-arshad-and-clev231)

Answer (score 11):

Here is another solution which dumps the table to a comma separated string:

```
using System.Data;

public static string DumpDataTable(DataTable table)
        {
            string data = string.Empty;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            if (null != table && null != table.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dataRow in table.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (var item in dataRow.ItemArray)
                    {
                        sb.Append(item);
                        sb.Append(',');
                    }
                    sb.AppendLine();
                }

                data = sb.ToString();
            }
            return data;
        }
```

Answer (score 11):

Proper Tabular display

```
static void print_results(DataTable data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Dictionary<string, int> colWidths = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        foreach (DataColumn col in data.Columns)
        {
            Console.Write(col.ColumnName);
            var maxLabelSize = data.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                    .Select(m => (m.Field<object>(col.ColumnName)?.ToString() ?? "").Length)
                    .OrderByDescending(m => m).FirstOrDefault();

            colWidths.Add(col.ColumnName, maxLabelSize);
            for (int i = 0; i < maxLabelSize - col.ColumnName.Length + 10; i++) Console.Write(" ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (DataRow dataRow in data.Rows)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dataRow.ItemArray.Length; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(dataRow.ItemArray[j]);
                for (int i = 0; i < colWidths[data.Columns[j].ColumnName] - dataRow.ItemArray[j].ToString().Length + 10; i++) Console.Write(" ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the following extension method (C# 9.0):

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides extension methods for the <see cref="DataTable"/> type.
/// </summary>
public static class DataTableExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Generates a textual representation of the data of <paramref name="table"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="table">The table to print.</param>
    /// <returns>A textual representation of the data of <paramref name="table"/>.</returns>
    public static String Print(this DataTable table)
    {
        String GetCellValueAsString(DataRow row, DataColumn column)
        {
            var cellValue = row[column];
            var cellValueAsString = cellValue is null or DBNull ? "{{null}}" : cellValue.ToString();

            return cellValueAsString;
        }

        var columnWidths = new Dictionary<DataColumn, Int32>();

        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
        {
            columnWidths.Add(column, column.ColumnName.Length);
        }

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            {
                columnWidths[column] = Math.Max(columnWidths[column], GetCellValueAsString(row, column).Length);
            }
        }

        var resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        resultBuilder.Append("| ");

        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
        {
            resultBuilder.Append(column.ColumnName.PadRight(columnWidths[column]));
            resultBuilder.Append(" | ");
        }

        resultBuilder.AppendLine();

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            resultBuilder.Append("| ");

            foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            {
                resultBuilder.Append(GetCellValueAsString(row, column).PadRight(columnWidths[column]));
                resultBuilder.Append(" | ");
            }

            resultBuilder.AppendLine();
        }

        return resultBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
foreach (DataRow dr in myDataTable.Rows)
{
    foreach (var item in dr.ItemArray)
    {
        Console.Write(item + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> A previous answer was similar to this, but didnt cleanly format the separation between line entries and cells

Comment: This should be a comment under the answer you refer to, not an answer of its own. It does not provide a novel response or solution to the problem posed by OP.

Comment: Stack Overflow Users want answers as concise as possible. The most concise answer given was the one I alluded to, but it couldn't show what was being outputted, which was important to see how the loop actually worked - this was what prompted me, the very same person, looking for a concise answer, to improve on the answer. In any case, the upvotes disagree with you.

Comment: Repeating most of an answer isn't very concise, compared to a comment that just says (add `Console.WriteLine` to show output. Also, don't get led astray by scores, people upvote bad content all the time.

Answer (score 3):

This is done by data table that holds single table

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from info", con);
        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        ad.Fill(dt);
        Console.WriteLine(dt.Columns[0].ColumnName.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[1].ItemArray[0].ToString());
```

This is done by data set that holds set of table

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from info", con);
        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataSet dt = new DataSet();
        ad.Fill(dt);
        Console.WriteLine(dt.Tables[0].Columns[0].ColumnName.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(dt.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString());
```

both will give same result. only data set contains number of index of table.

Answer (score 1):

**Print Datatable contents rows with column**

```
DataTable datatableinfo= new DataTable();

//Fill data table 

//datatableinfo=fill by function or get data from database

//Print data table with rows and column


for (int j = 0; j < datatableinfo.Rows.Count; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < datatableinfo.Columns.Count; i++)    
        {    
            Console.Write(datatableinfo.Columns[i].ColumnName + " ");    
            Console.WriteLine(datatableinfo.Rows[j].ItemArray[i]); 
        }
}


Ouput :
ColumnName - row Value
ColumnName - row Value
ColumnName - row Value
ColumnName - row Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on another answer here, here's a method that converts a DataTable to CSV output and adds the column names as the first row in the output:

```
public static string DataTableToCsv(DataTable table)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    if (table != null && table.Rows != null && table.Columns != null && table.Columns.Count > 0)
    {
        int lastItemIndex = table.Columns.Count - 1;
        int index = 0;

        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
        {
            resultBuilder.Append(column.ColumnName);

            if (index < lastItemIndex)       // if not the last element in the row
                resultBuilder.Append(", ");  // add the separator

            index++;
        }

        resultBuilder.AppendLine();  // add a CRLF after column names row

        foreach (DataRow dataRow in table.Rows)
        {
            lastItemIndex = dataRow.ItemArray.Length - 1;
            index = 0;

            foreach (object item in dataRow.ItemArray)
            {
                resultBuilder.Append(item);

                if (index < lastItemIndex)       // if not the last element in the row
                    resultBuilder.Append(", ");  // add the separator

                index++;
            }

            resultBuilder.AppendLine();  // add a CRLF after each data row
        }

        result = resultBuilder.ToString();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Usage example:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
....
Console.WriteLine(DataTableToCsv(table));
```

Note that this method does not properly handle (i.e., escape) data that contains quotes or commas.  But it should be sufficient as a quick and dirty way to dump a data table to the console or anywhere else for viewing.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following extension method.

```
public static string ToCSV(this DataTable t, bool header)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;
    int maxColIdx = 0;
    
    if (t?.Columns?.Count > 0)
    {
        maxColIdx = t.Columns.Count - 1;
        if (header)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn c in t.Columns)
            {
                sb.Append(c.ColumnName);
                if (i < maxColIdx) sb.Append(", ");
                i++;
            }
            sb.AppendLine();
        }

        if (t?.Rows?.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow r in t.Rows)
            {
                i = 0;
                foreach (var item in r.ItemArray)
                {
                    sb.Append(item);
                    if( i < maxColIdx) sb.Append(',');
                    i++;
                }
                sb.AppendLine();
            }
        }
    }           
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Function to both print DataTable and DataRow.

```
    private void printDataTable(DataTable Table)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dataRow in Table.Rows)
        {
            printDataRow(dataRow);
        }
    }

    private void printDataRow(DataRow drow)
    {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", drow.ItemArray));
        Console.WriteLine(sb);

    }
```